# The choice SELECT doesn't work, only 1 value boots, and there is a lot of them, help with a code

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

```
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
    listName: "Telekom Group",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Name' /><FieldRef Name='NameEng' /><FieldRef Name='Country' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Country" /><Value Type="Text">' + 'Test' + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>',
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        liHtml = "<option value=''>" + $(this).attr("ows_Name") + "</option>";
    });
    $("#ManagerIT").html(liHtml);
}
```

})

```
<select title="ManagerIT" id="ManagerIT" listFieldName='ManagerIT' class='formInput'></select>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific on the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question, you need to populate the choice field in form with Choice field column from SPList. Correct me if i am wrong.

In you code, i do not see the code to append the choice fields. Might be due to that, its just displaying last item from choice field.

In loop , Could you try below line of code?

```
liHtml += "<option value=''>" + $(this).attr("ows_Name") + "</option>";
```